# booking system on the android applicatoins

Tags: android

I want to implement a booking system on the android application. I do some searches in the web. I has been find this page(and also some related page in the android developer site):

http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_overview.html

but as you can see in this topic has been commented that just digital content are allowed. but I has been see that many applications has booking systems so how they do these?

Thanks

Comment: So what exactly do you want ? A *booking* system as booking a seat in a restaurant ?

Comment: Yes some thing like what you said. a booking system for a parking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can achieve this by two ways. First you can have virtual currency in your app which will be digital content, and then sell whatever you want to using that virtual currency. 
apart from that you can have other payment methods like banks, paypal etc. Most apps implement this only.

Comment: thanks for your reply. do you have know any applications that you paypal or etc. at their apps. Also some links or tutorials for using them in my application?